# data in multiple rows into single row (values not standard)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

here's my problem:

I have a table with Names and Addresses, e.g.

```
Name  |  Address       | Updated
----------------------------------
a     |  12 lane       | 1/1/2011
b     |  34 avenue     | 1/1/2011
c     |  56 district   | 1/1/2011
a     |  78 avenue     | 8/8/2011
b     |  90 lane       | 8/8/2011
a     |  83 district   | 9/9/2011
a     |  39 road       | 10/10/2011
```

As you can see, it's possible for people to have multiple addresses. Let's say the maximum number of addresses one person has is 5.

I'm only interested in getting the newest 3 addresses for each person, such that the table would look like:

```
Name  |  Address_1      |   Address_2       |  Address_3
--------------------------------------------------------------
a     | 78 avenue       |   83 district     | 39 road
b     | 34 avenue       |   90 lane         | NULL
c     | 56 district     |   NULL            | NULL
```

Note that a's first entry "12 lane" doesn't appear

I've been reading other examples shown on stackoverflow, but i'm not sure if Pivot tables are suitable for what I need, since the addresses are all different

Thanks in advance for any help rendered!

Comment: What you have done till right now?

Comment: I've been trying to concatenate all the addresses into one column.. about to try to split them up into the 3 address fields i need to populate. Thanks for the blazing quick replies Johan and Nikola! I'm gonna try Nikola's method first as it looks short and sweet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pivot it. Key point is assigning row_numbers to addresses in descending order of updates. This produces column names 1, 2, and 3 (and 4, 5 - but these will be ignored by pivot command).

[Here is Sql Fiddle with example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e65ad/8).

```
select name, 
       [1] Address_1,
       [2] Address_2,
       [3] Address_3
from
(
  select name,
         address,
         row_number() over (partition by name
                            order by updated desc) rn
    from table1
) o
pivot (min(address) for rn in ([1], [2], [3])) p
```

Comment: thanks Nikola, this works perfectly and is elegantly written!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple query using `ROW_NUMBER()`

Since you only want three address columns this might be suitable. The solution is not suitable for a non fix amount of columns.

```
;with testdata(Name, Address, Updated)
as
(
select 'a','12 lane',convert(datetime, '1/1/2011')
union all
select 'b','34 avenue',convert(datetime, '1/1/2011')
union all
select 'c','56 district',convert(datetime, '1/1/2011')
union all
select 'a','78 avenue',convert(datetime, '8/8/2011')
union all
select 'b','90 lane',convert(datetime, '8/8/2011')
union all
select 'a','83 district',convert(datetime, '9/9/2011')
union all
select 'a','39 road',convert(datetime, '10/10/2011')
)
,tmp
as
(
select  * 
        ,row_number() over(PARTITION by Name order by Updated desc) as rn
from testdata
)
select  x.Name
        ,x.Address
        ,y.Address
        ,z.Address
from    tmp x
left join   tmp y
    on  x.Name = y.Name
    and y.rn = 2
left join   tmp z
    on  x.Name = z.Name
    and z.rn = 3
where x.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to use two queries:

- The first using the DISTINCT key to get the unique "names".
- The second, in a loop over the unique names, to get for each name the 3 most recent addresses, using the TOP clause (in your case TOP 3) and an "ORDER BY Updated DESC" specification.
- Of course, the queries may be combined using a suitable JOIN.